# How do i add invisible buttons to my screen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, pygame

So i decided to add buttons in my game, since I already made the design for the buttons all I needed were invisible buttons "on top" of the buttons that are already there which would make a beep sound whenever you hover about it and clicking it takes the user to the specified place.

I've tried researching on how I could do this, but I either find the wrong tutorial or find some extremely vague/bad instruction on how to add buttons.

Comment: Invisible buttons sound like a great idea, but you may be better off looking at the decorator design pattern. (Not to be confused with python’s own decorators)

Comment: When I said ‘looking at the decorator pattern’ what I meant was ‘google the decorator pattern’.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you played the sound during the button functionality, like this:

```
def button(x, y, w, h, inactive, active, action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y:
        gameDisplay.blit(active, (x, y))
        if click[0] == 1 and action is not None:
            action()
            button_sound = mixer.Sound("button_click.wav")
            button_sound.play()
    else:
        gameDisplay.blit(inactive, (x, y))
```